# expresso Store: Inventory not showing in cp for client's member group

Tags: expresso-store

I created a member group for the client, with this two options:
- Can access ADD-ONS: Modules > yes
- Can access module:  Store > yes

When i access with the client profile , i can see the "store" tab, but "Inventory" is not present

why? Thanks in advance

Comment: It requires `Can access ADD-ONS section` too have enabled as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the Inventory page/menu item is controlled by your client's access to your products channel(s).

Double check in your member group settings, under "Channel Assignment", that your client's member group has the privilege "Can post and edit entries in: Products" (or whatever your products channel is called).

If more than one channel has a Store Product Details fieldtype, your client's member group must have access to **all** these channels.

Comment: Not working for me :\ More here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20693/ee-members-group-expresso-store-and-cp-store-button-issue