# Expresso Store: Inventory not showing in CP menu for client's member group

Tags: expresso-store, control-panel

I'm having the same problem as [this post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4809/expresso-store-inventory-not-showing-in-cp-for-clients-member-group), only the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

Sorry for re-posting the question, but I didn't if I can carry on a "me too" conversation in the answer thread?

When setting up a client's Member Group, I can't get *Inventory* to appear in the **Store** menu. I even duplicated the Super Admin's Member Group with all its privileges, but yet still couldn't get this to work. It seems that only {group_id==1} is able to see the Inventory tab.

This is an MSM site and even with the client's member group having access to all store-related channels in all sites, it's still a no-go...

EE 2.6.1, Store 1.6.4

Comment: Are your products entered into the same site that you're unable to see the Inventory menu option for? With MSM based sites products and orders don't swap between sites so you can't see the inventory of another site.

Comment: Hi Ian (am back from holiday/vacation, thanks for being patient). "Yes" the products are in the same MSM site as the menu item I'm looking for.

Comment: In my case it requires to have allowed `Can access ADD-ONS section`

Answer (score 1):

To access the inventory tab in Store, a customer must have permission to edit/create entries in your products channel.

Make sure you have set up a products channel for this site, and then make sure that the member group can create entries under Content > Publish. If that is possible but you still don't see the Inventory menu item, send an email to support@exp-resso.com and we will investigate.

Comment: Well, similar problem and cannot get access to Store for a group member. More here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20693/ee-members-group-expresso-store-and-cp-store-button-issue