# EE Members Group + Expresso Store and CP "Store" button issue

Tags: expresso-store

I have created new Members Group with following privileges:

```
- Can access the control panel
- Can access CONTENT section
- Can access CONTENT: Publish
- Can access CONTENT: Edit
- Can access CONTENT: File Manager
- Can access ADD-ONS: Modules
- Can post and edit entries in: Products
- Can access module: Store
```

but I'm not able to see "Store" button in the control panel

I'm running EE 2.7.3 and Store 2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I forgot to enable `Can access ADD-ONS section`

Mea culpa